# Twitter API code 32 401 unauthorized via postman

Tags: rest, twitter, twitter-oauth, postman

I am trying to get tweets from a user with his screen name, but I am getting code 32 401 unauthorized error, i tried encoding the details it's not working, Please let me know what is the issue here

Below is the get request I am sending via postman, I have attached photo for more understanding

```
GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=urstrulyMahesh HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="hwWrdsCbnYA6duRPn9b5eOL2b",oauth_token="920656878140645376-spRRFqnUdYyRKXJdP2Bd1SuN1TeJP8B",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1508349347",oauth_nonce="JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC123DEFGHI494",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="A0mdEkSUjwWOO8AfX0S4oU296Q4%253D"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b5bfb83b-e2c6-0e23-81b0-38daee989fec
```

[image]

I am sure access tokens and customer tokens are entered correctly

Please point out the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because your Authorization header doesn't follow the OAuth protocol. All of your credentials are in plain text, but the value must pass through several steps of encoding and encryption before they can be sent to Twitter. You'll have to do this with code because part of the protocol includes a timestamp, which is likely to expire before you can do it by hand. Here's the process, on Twitter's site:

[Authorizing a Request](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request)

There are several 3rd party [Twitter Libraries](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries) that do this in several programming languages. One of the things you might be able to do is write the code with the same parameters you're using for Postman, set a breakpoint, and copy the Authorization header when the code hits the breakpoint.

> Note: You've posted code and a picture with your application secrets.
>   That means that anyone who wants to can use your secrets to interact
>   with Twitter on your behalf. To protect yourself, you should either
>   re-key or delete the Twitter application (if it was just for test) and
>   create a new one with new secrets.